# How to run/debug Ruby Cucumber tests in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: ruby, intellij-idea, cucumber

I launch my Cucumber tests from a shell with the command `bundle exec cucumber -p local features`.

**Questions:**

1. How to do the same with help of IntelliJ IDEA?
2. How to debug the tests with IntelliJ IDEA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[There is a Ruby plugin for IntelliJ.](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?idea&pluginId=1293) I'm not personally familiar with it (I use RubyMine), but I expect that it has dedicated run/debug support for Cucumber like RubyMine does.

Comment: RubyMine is essentially a plugin for IntelliJ, so I wouldn't expect there to be much difference/friction with usage.